# How do I decode Unicode HTML Entities for XML in Java

Tags: java, unicode, html-entities, xml-encoding

```
String htmlToXml = "<div>Lorem dorum 漢字  is &gt; <p>&eacute;</p></div>";
String xmlString = unescapeUnicodeHtml(htmlToXml);
assert "<div>Lorem dorum 漢字  is &gt; <p>é</p></div>".equals(xmlString);
```

Is there a library that I can use to implement `unescapeUnicodeHtml`? If not, what is the best way to implement it?

Comment: This one? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: was there a particular method you had in mind?

Comment: FYI: I've been trying to use this library without success... the problem is trying to retain the &gt; and unescape the &eacute; (as the latter breaks the XML parser I'm using

Comment: The library does it correctly, I think your usecase isn't correct. &gt; unescaped is realy > . In your case I would first replace all &gt; &lt; with something else (say |gt; for example) unescape it and then replace the |gt; back with &gt;